# Wamp server doesnt start

Tags: dll, windows-7, installation, wamp

After installng in my WIN7 32-bit os . I get this error after installation is done **"The program cant start because MSVcr100.dll is misssing from your computer . try reinstalling the program to fix this problem ."** . What should i do to fix this problem ?

Comment: have you tried re-install like what message said?

Comment: Yes i did . But still the same error .

Comment: @ChristopheD I ll try that .

Comment: @ChristopheD Installing that didnt help . Same error .

Comment: see best ans: http://www.steptoinstall.com/msvcr100-dll-is-missing-when-wamp-server-install.html

Answer (score 1):

Had that problem a while ago, I remember having to download [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555) for it to work. Try installing it and checking again.

Comment: Are you using Windows 7 32 bit ?

Comment: Yes, it was the Windows 7 Professional 32-bit edition.

Comment: I was succesfull in installing WAMP , Should i stop the IIS ???

Comment: If you're running wampserver in localhost you should stop IIS.However, you can run both if you change the port on wampserver.

Comment: even when i stop IIS it goes to iis page  .So changed the port to 8080 and was successful in getting the local host page . but there is some error in phpmyadmin .

Comment: Error

MySQL said: Documentation
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: What's the color of the wampserver icon in the taskbar? Also, what does it show when you hover over it with your cursor?

Comment: Its orange in color . Its say "WAMPSERVER-Online".

Comment: Is the MySQL service installed and started?
Click on the wampserver icon and navigate to MySQL -> Service.
If you've set a password for users you can change it in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php
You can also open the "MySQL log" to get more details.

Comment: every thing is set . But still not loading .